# Stack overflow before debugging main function in amd64

Tags: c++, memory, dll

I have a working 32 bit application with several dependency. A rough estimation of the dependency is like below -

[handshake_win32.exe] ----> [libhandshake32.dll] ----> [libeay32, ssleay32.dll] ----> [zlib1.dll]

Now I would like to use my libhandshake32.dll through JNI for code reuse. As the JVM is  64-bit so I guess those library needed to be recompiled for x64 arch.

My first target is running the current baseline handshake_win32.exe in x64. So I have recompiled all the dll for x64. But after successful recompilation when I start into debug mode I am getting immediate Stack Overflow at main function.

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007f602f79567 in handshake_win32.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

I have tried to check the dll signature with dumpbin and it seems all have machine type x64.
dependency walker gives the following error message for all of x64 modules -

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing
>   export function in an implicitly dependent module. Error: Modules with
>   different CPU types were found.

It shows that x86 version of MSVCR100.dll was loaded where the actual dll's arch is x64.

Can anyone suggest what are the possible causes of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to capture the stack overflow in the debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger only shows the following error : Unhandled exception at 0x000007f602f79567 in handshake_win32.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1、If you use cmd/bat to compile your dlls,
start the cmd/bat this way:

```
%comspec% /k ""PATH_TO_VS\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64
```

or

```
%comspec% /k ""PATH_TO_VS\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64
```

instead of:

```
%comspec% /k ""PATH_TO_VS\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

2、if you use gui, you'd better check the command line:

```
c/c++->command line
linker->command line
```

Sometimes, when you change your configeration in vs gui, the command lines do not change,
you'd better start a new project and copy your soure files there.

Comment: I ran the x64 VS Command line tool, and after compilation I test them with the built in test suite. It shows that every test case is passed both for openssl & zlib. Anyother clues?

Comment: Copy the zlib and openssl dlls to your exe output folder, to make sure the right dlls are loaded. Chech the lib path, too. By the way, which option do you use, MT or MD? Do all the projects use the same MT/MD option?

Comment: Yes, They have same configuration (MultiThreaded DLL).

I also copied the DLLs to output directory (32 bit runs just fine).

Comment: Oh, that's weird. But you can get a win64 distribute here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (with header files and libs)

Comment: thnx I will try with that and update the thread accordingly ... :)